# UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits: Printing out ALL of them FOR an Entire Font family

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I've been working on my fonts and it turns our that I need a way to be able to print out ALL `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` for a specific font. The way it's set up now is that you can only only guess at which of the 21 symbolic traits a font may posesess in order to determine whether a font is supported for something like `UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded`, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to just do something where I plug a font name in and magically the `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` show up on in the debugger. Now I can query this for a font and it does return the "enum" numerical values but this seems like something that Apple may already have available for our use but I'm coming up on dead ends. I can only get the enum numerical values and nothing else. I'm using this method below one by one to find these traits and it's pretty annoying:

```
UIFontDescriptor *helveticaNeueFamily = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes: @{UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: @"Helvetica"}];

helveticaNeueFamily=[helveticaNeueFamily fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded];
NSArray *matches = reallyMatchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys(helveticaNeueFamily, nil);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it, this is a lot of code, but that's okay, the work has been done already:

The main Method, for example, if you want to see all symbolic descriptors, it's this:

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++) {
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
    [self findFontDescriptors:fontFamily size:14];
}
```

Methods, this work with the method above, and return what you are looking for. You can use it by just using the methods below and then plugging in the name of the font and it's size, but the loop above shows everything for all system fonts:

```
-(void)findFontDescriptors:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitItalic:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitBold:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitBold");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitVertical:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitVertical");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorTraitLooseLeading:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorTraitLooseLeading");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassMask:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassMask");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassUnknown:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassUnknown");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassOldStyleSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassOldStyleSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassTransitionalSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassTransitionalSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassModernSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassModernSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassClarendonSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassClarendonSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassSlabSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassSlabSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassFreeformSerifs:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassFreeformSerifs");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassSansSerif:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassSansSerif");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassOrnamentals:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassOrnamentals");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassScripts:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassScripts");
    }
    if ([self isUIFontDescriptorClassSymbolic:fontName size:size]) {
        NSLog(@"UIFontDescriptorClassSymbolic");
    }
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitBold:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitItalic:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitVertical:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitVertical) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorTraitLooseLeading:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitLooseLeading) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassMask:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassMask) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassUnknown:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassUnknown) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassOldStyleSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassOldStyleSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassTransitionalSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassTransitionalSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassModernSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassModernSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassClarendonSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassClarendonSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassSlabSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassSlabSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassFreeformSerifs:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassFreeformSerifs) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassSansSerif:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassSansSerif) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassOrnamentals:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassOrnamentals) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassScripts:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassScripts) != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isUIFontDescriptorClassSymbolic:(NSString*)fontName size:(float)size {
    UIFont* fonts = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symTraits = fonts.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    return (symTraits & UIFontDescriptorClassSymbolic) != 0;
}
```

Now, if you are super hardcore and want to go deeper, you can use this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size: 12.0];
CFArrayRef fontFeatures = CTFontCopyFeatures((__bridge CTFontRef) font);
NSLog(@"properties = %@", fontFeatures);
```

This above method will return some very neat features of fonts that are different from the ones above, sort of. There's a great guide that Apple has out on this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542

And just to have some fun with this, lets print out all font descriptors:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6ddb0f525b513b10941

here's the format:

> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.681 [25332:2371074] Marion: (
>       "Marion-Italic",
>       "Marion-Bold",
>       "Marion-Regular" )
>
> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.681 [25332:2371074] UIFontDescriptorClassMask
>
> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.681 [25332:2371074] UIFontDescriptorClassSansSerif
>
> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.681 [25332:2371074]
>   UIFontDescriptorClassOrnamentals
>
> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.681 [25332:2371074] UIFontDescriptorClassScripts
>
> 2015-08-27 05:32:28.682 [25332:2371074] UIFontDescriptorClassSymbolic

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps you had to do something like this, I've looked for a standard 5 liner solution and there's literally nothing out there that apple has put together, but this does in deed work, people don't realize what a headache it is to  NEVER know what your fonts can really do, this is great!